# Play audio with gapless playback

Tags: sound, vlc

I am looking for a way to play audio files without interruptions between tracks. So far, I used VLC all the time, but there is no gapless playback option. and it seems they don't plan to implement that

Is there a way to play audio files with gapless playback in Ubuntu?

I found [this](https://code.videolan.org/tguillem/vlc/-/tree/gapless-mr) fork of VLC which seems to add gapless playback by default, how do I install it on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solutions for gapless playback, including lame encoded mp3 files, I found are

1. mpd, music player daemon. Not a traditional music player and rather cumbersome to set up.
2. Audacious, a simple music player which I now use. It fully supports audiophile features such as (perfect) gapless playback and replaygain.

It has been a while since I last tested, but then I did not find any other audio players that, if they could play gapless for some file formats in the first place, also could do it for lame encoded mp3 files. I certainly never had good experiences with Rythmbox, but things could have changed by now.

Answer (score 2):

Rhythmbox plays gapless by default.